# SugarCRM - create CommentLog with API v10

Tags: php, postman, sugarcrm

I'm looking for a way to make an entry in the `CommentLog` with the `SugarCRM` API. I made the first attempts with PHP and the rest-php-client, but unfortunately found no way to write or read the `CommentLog`.

With Postman I can authenticate myself, use the token, `read/create/update` leads or accounts. Unfortunately, for example, I cannot make an entry in the `CommentLog` for a case.

My used endpoints are `$url/rest/v10/CommentLog/$CaseId (POST)` or `$url/rest/v10/CommentLog (GET)`, booth without any success.

I see a `addComment` function on `/rest/v10/help`, but i dont know, how it works.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the CommentLog acts like a relationship, so one way could be something like `POST $url/rest/v10/Cases/$CaseId/link/commentlog_link` to create a new CommentLog record that is linked to r specified Case. (Check /help for payload format). I'm not sure about the link name "commentlog_link" though; Maybe I can investigate or test it myself later.

Comment: I think commentlog_link is an endpoint. But I dont'n know, what the body should look like. `{
    "description": {
        "comment": "Full text of the note"
    }
}` it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this;

**PUT** rest/v10/Bugs/01114102-319a-11ec-b680-acde48001122 (<- replace the module and id here)

Body:

```
{
  "commentlog_link": {
    "create": [{"entry": "The comment goes here", 
    "_link": "commentlog_link", 
    "deleted": false}], 
    "add": [], 
    "delete": []
  }
}
```

Verified using Sugar version 11.0.2